# Scalable image with text next to it

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make image near text scalable and responsive. Currently, when I run my html page, there is div which looks like this:

[image]

It's good, but when I try resize my window, it'll look like this:
[image]

When the text wrap under image, I want set image style to `width: 100%;`.

Is there any possible way to make image scale, when text is under it, but keep it, when there is enough place to put the text near the image?
It should look like this:

[image]

My current code

```css
.cake {
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.cake p {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  text-align: justify;
}

.cake>.price {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.cake>img {
  padding-right: 20px;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 240px;
  max-width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.price {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="cake">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/xWRtGkj.jpg">
  <h4>Cheesecake</h4>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
  </p>
  <span class="price">45</span>
</div>
```

Comment: upload your photo in `imgur` and add it, your view and available code view is different

Comment: you should have a look into flexbox instead of using `float` to position your items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use flexbox for this but if you don't want to change your code into `flexbox`, you can do it like below

```css
.cake {
    background-color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
.cake p {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-align: justify;
}
.cake > .price {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.cake > img {
    padding-right: 20px;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 240px;
    height: 200px;
    display: block;
    object-fit: cover;
}
.price {
    float: right;
}

@media (min-width: 430px) {
    .cake > img {
        max-width: 300px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="cake">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/xWRtGkj.jpg">
  <h4>Cheesecake</h4>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
  </p>
  <span class="price">45</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use media query [Using media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

```
.cake {
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.cake p {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  text-align: justify;
}

.cake>.price {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.cake>img {
  padding-right: 20px;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 240px;
  max-width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.price {
  float: right;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) { /*put the breakpoint where the text wrap*/
  .cake p {
     width: 100%;
   }
}
```